# xPath more predicates to select a node

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, appium

I would select a node by specifying more predicates. To do that I have done in this way as explained on w3schools site [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp) :

```
/bookstore/book[price>29 and price<50]
```

But I would ask you if there are difference between this way to do and the following :

```
/bookstore/book[price>29][price<50]
```

I wonder it because on internet I see many people do in this last way, but if I use it on Appium for native Android application the result is not consistent, a sort of randomic result .  Can be the predicates format fault ?

Answer (score 1):

Your two expressions are completely equivalent.

The only time they would not be equivalent is if one of the predicates (explicitly or implicitly) is numeric or depends on position(): for example

/x/y[price>3][position()=1]

does not mean the same as

/x/y[price>3 and position()=1]